# Flutter void function with parameter

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi all I'm in the process of learning Flutter with Dart.

My original function was to this

```
  void _answerQuestion() {
    setState(() {
      _questionIndex++;
    });
  }
```

And then called it like this, which all works fine

```
body: (_questionIndex < _questions.length)
        ? Quiz(
            answerQuestion: _answerQuestion,
            questionIndex: _questionIndex,
            questions: _questions,
          )
        : Result(),
    )
```

however I have changed it to this

```
  void _answerQuestion(int score) {
    _totalScore += score;
    setState(() {
      _questionIndex++;
    });
  }
```

which now has an issue when I try to point to it. I now have other issues in the code however this I think is the root problem. The error is

```
The argument type 'void Function(int)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function()'.dartargument_type_not_assignable
```

Has anyone got any clues? I am using the following Dart version sdk: '>=2.18.5 <3.0.0'

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your `answerQuestion` parameter in the `Quiz` constructor needs to be of type `void Function(int)` now, since you want to pass an int.

The next error will pop up when you *call* that function, in that place you need to pass whatever you want for `score`.

Comment: in my Quiz class I have 

 "final VoidCallback answerQuestion;"

Comment: @andrewslaughter `VoidCallback` is a typedef for `void Function();` so they are the same: a function that does not take parameters and returns nothing. In your code you are passing to a parameter of this type a value that is a Function type that takes an integer, which won't work because it is considered a different type

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help and feedback. I don't really understand what your saying. Are you saying that you can't pass parameters to a void function in Dart?

Comment: Yes. That is why it's called a `void` function. You want a function with an `int` parameter, so just declare it like that. `final void Function(int) answerQuestion;`

Comment: But it doesn't return anything, hence the void.

Comment: Yes... *that* `void` is still there. Did you try what I wrote?

Comment: Hi all, thanks for your help. Not sure if this is what you meant but I have changed the declaration in the Quiz class to 

final Function answerQuestion; 

this seems to of fixed it.